# Error 403 after adding virtualhost

Tags: apache

This is my directive inside /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.somedomain.com
    DocumentRoot "srv/http/subdir"
        <Directory '/srv/http/subdir'>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When i try to access any file inside subdir, i get 403 access denied error. I tred restarting apache, i changed ownership of all files inside /srv/http to http:http too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the options directive since you've already declared a document root. I would remove that whole block. You need to declare default files though. Like:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php default.html

Also, check your site logs or apache logs to see a more detailed error.

Here's an example of one of my virtual directories:

```
    ServerAdmin somememail@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/directoryname
    ServerName yoursite.com
    ServerAlias www.yoursite.com 


    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Comment: You can uncomment the error log portion and set it to your own location.

Comment: You can determine that the above is accurate by actually naming the filename you are trying to hit in your url.